# Return custom Error in Union Graphql Type while show list data | returning list with union type in graphql

Tags: express, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I'm using Apollo server for my project returning list(array) of data when I try to return `Error` union type it shows this error:

```
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Expected Iterable, but did not find one for field \"Query.getReports\".",
```

My Schema:

```
type Query {
    getReports(id: ID!, patient_id: Int): [getReportUnion]!
  }

  union getReportUnion = Error | getReportResult 

  type getReportResult {
    id: ID!
    patient_id: Int!
  }

  type Error {
    error: Boolean!
    message: String!
  }
```

my Resolver:

```
  getReports: async (parent: any, args: any, context: any, info: any) => {
    /**
     * Simplify
     */
    const { id, patient_id } = args;
    const { isAuth, userId } = context.Auth;
    
    /**
     * Authenticating user is logged in
     */
    if (!!!isAuth || userId !== id)
      return { __typename: "Error", error: err, message: mesg };

   // if a user is logged in then it works well
  }
```

and my query:

```
query {
  getReports(id: "5f449b73e2ccbc43aa5204d88", patient_id: 0) {
  __typename
    ... on getReportResult {
            patient_id
      date
    }
    ... on Error {
      error
      message
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is when I tried to pass the wrong `id` argument or `jwt token`, it shows the error. if every `id` and `jwt token` as header are right then it works like charm. so question is when  `id` or `jwt token` is wrong, I want to show the `Error` type to inform user something isn't alright!

I already tried but not working:

```
 type Query {
        getReports(id: ID!, patient_id: Int): getReportUnion!
      }
    
      union getReportUnion = Error | [getReportResult]
```

it shows another error, is there any workaround to get rid of this error and show the `Error`. your answer is valuable to us!

Comment: Why this king of error handling???? Do you want to return an array with SOME failed reports/items instead of failing entire query (usual throwing graphql error) ? https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/errors/

Comment: @xadm thanks for your suggestion! I prefer to return a custom error instead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your field's type is a List, then your resolver must return either an [iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterable_protocol) (i.e. an array) or a Promise that resolves to one.

The type for your field is a List (`[getReportUnion]`). However, inside your resolver, you are returning an object literal:

```
return { __typename: "Error", error: err, message: mesg }
```

You should return an array instead:

```
return [{ __typename: "Error", error: err, message: mesg }]
```

There is no way for you to return *either* a List of `getReportResult` objects or a single `Error` object. The only way to do that would be to wrap `getReportResult` with another type and use that type inside your union instead.

```
type Query {
    getReports(id: ID!, patient_id: Int): GetReportPayload!
  }

  union GetReportPayload = Error | GetReportResults

  type GetReportResults {
    results: [Report!]!
  }

  type Report {
    id: ID!
    patientId: Int!
  }

  type Error {
    error: Boolean!
    message: String!
  }
```